# Sublime 3 PSR4 Plugin

Tags: php, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, psr-4

Is there a plugin for Sublime 3 to automatically do PSR4 configuration?

I am working with a third-party library that's quite old now and needs PSR updating.

I've heard you can do something like this using PHPStorm

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no plugin for Sublime 3 to automatically do PSR4 configuration.  PHPFMT plugin for Sublime 3 has PSR1 and PSR2 configuration: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/phpfmt

If you want to be able to format your PHP in PSR4, the IDE PHPStorm has the option to do so.